# How to get test plan results from a TFS server

Tags: c#, tfs

I have created a project that connects to the server and then gets the test plans, but I'm struggling with getting the test plan results (number of passed, failed and active test cases).
The code below is the code I use for getting the test plans. Any suggestions on how to get the test results for these plans? Or how can I get test run results for a single test case. I can filter out the test plans, suites and cases I want to, but I can't find results anywhere.

```
void GetTestPlans(ITestManagementTeamProject testproject)
    {
        ITestPlanCollection plans = testproject.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan");

        TreeViewItem root = null;
        root = new TreeViewItem();
        root.Header = ImageHelpers.CreateHeader(testproject.WitProject.Name, ItemTypes.TeamProject);
        TreeMain.Items.Add(root);

        foreach (ITestPlan plan in plans)
        {
            if (plan.Name.Contains("C600 Update"))
            {
                TreeViewItem plan_tree = new TreeViewItem();
                string header = plan.Id + "\t" + plan.Name;
                plan_tree.Header = ImageHelpers.CreateHeader(header, ItemTypes.TestPlan);


                if (plan.RootSuite != null && plan.RootSuite.Entries.Count > 0)
                    GetPlanSuites(plan.RootSuite.Entries, plan_tree);

                root.Items.Add(plan_tree);

            }
        }

    }


    void GetPlanSuites(ITestSuiteEntryCollection suites, TreeViewItem tree_item)
    {

        foreach (ITestSuiteEntry suite_entry in suites)
        {
            IStaticTestSuite suite = suite_entry.TestSuite as IStaticTestSuite;
            if (suite != null)
            {
                TreeViewItem suite_tree = new TreeViewItem();
                suite_tree.Header = ImageHelpers.CreateHeader(suite.Title, ItemTypes.TestSuite);

                GetTestCases(suite, suite_tree);

                tree_item.Items.Add(suite_tree);

                if (suite.Entries.Count > 0)
                    GetPlanSuites(suite.Entries, suite_tree);

            }
        }
    }

    void GetTestCases(IStaticTestSuite suite, TreeViewItem tree_item)
    {
        //AllTestCases - Will show all the Test Cases under that Suite even in sub suites.
        //ITestCaseCollection testcases = suite.AllTestCases;

        //Will bring only the Test Case under a specific Test Suite.
        ITestSuiteEntryCollection suiteentrys = suite.TestCases;

        foreach (ITestSuiteEntry testcase in suiteentrys)
        {
            ITestCase testCase = testcase.TestCase as ITestCase;
            TreeViewItem test = new TreeViewItem();
            string header = testcase.Id + "\t" + testcase.Title;
            test.Header = ImageHelpers.CreateHeader(header, ItemTypes.TestCase);
            tree_item.Items.Add(test);
            GetResults(testCase);
        }
    }


    void GetResults(ITestCase testCase)
    {
        // Would like to get the results for each test case here
        // If there are several test runs, only the latest counts


    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't a plan something that can be executed zero, one, or many times? Each execution would have its own results, no?

Comment: Get the test plan run first and then get the result in each run

Comment: I would like to get the test result for each of the test cases within the testplan. If a test case is not ran yet, it will have state "Active". Otherwise, it is the result from the last run test I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
testProject.TestResults.ByTestId(testCase.Id);
```

Comment: Please explain why this method would be advantageous to try.

Comment: In the asker's code snippet, there is a method called:

void GetResults(ITestCase testCase)

This is a response to that method.